# iPhone : what the best way to integrated iPhone application to other application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-snippets, code-reuse

I want to reuse iPhone source code application with other application, so in Xcode iPhone does it be able build library .jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".jar" is a Java archive format, so no. iPhones don't come with a jvm. You can build libraries though.

The best way to recycle your code from one application to the next is to try to write in the most general or abstract way you can, i.e. in such a way as to minimize the dependence on any given project.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reuse a whole application, but you can [create a static library](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=808/) and have other apps link to it.